# Working with Blocks in Drupal 7

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

How do you create a Region in Drupal 7 Also how do you print out the contents of that region in page.tpl.php?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1):

Open you theme's .info file, where regions have been defined. There if you want to add region you can add and have to write the following code in page.tpl to call

```
<?php if ($page['new_region']): ?>
  <div id="new_region" class="col new"><div class="section">
    <?php print render($page[new_region']); ?>
  </div></div> 
<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

This should help you: http://drupal.org/node/1088718#comment-4194802

Answer (score 0):

First you have to define region in your Theme's info file like this

```
regions[new] = New Region
```

Then add following code in your page.tpl.php

```
<?php if ($new): ?>
 <div id="new">
        <?php print $new; ?>
 </div>
<?php endif; ?>
```